# Return json in a sql query which is multiple related items

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a web app which shows a list if items.

Each Item can have a one or more tags.

Item(Id, Name)

Tag(Id, Name)

ItemTag(Id, ItemId, TagId)

If only showing a single item, it is easy enough to get the Item, and then the tags and show them in the UI.

However, when showing a grid of items, which may show 100 items, I want to avoid having to do 101 trips to the database - one to get the list of items, and then one round trip to the database for each set of tags for each item.

The best I have been able to come up with is doing the base query, then using the results to build a second query using the Ids to return one long list of Tag which I then match up to the individual items.

Is there a better way of doing this?  For example, if the list of tags could be turned into json and returned as a string in the original query, then on the client I could turn that back into objects and display them appropriately.  But I don't know how to write such a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE:  This question was originally tagged SQL Server 2012.

You are looking for string aggregation -- or something similar.  In SQL Server 2012+, the best method is probably this XML method which returns the tags in a comma-separated string:

```
SELECT i.*,
       STUFF( (SELECT ',' + t.name
               FROM tags t JOIN
                    ItemTags it
                    ON it.TagID = t.ID
               WHERE i.ID = it.ItemID
               ORDER BY t.name
               FOR XML PATH ('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
            ) as tags
WHERE i.Created >= '2018-01-01' and
      i.Created < '2018-02-01';
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever logic you come up with for selecting your Items can then be used on the Tags:

```
--suppose this returns 100 items
SELECT * FROM Items WHERE Created BETWEEN '2018-01-01' and '2018-02-01'

--select th tags from the items
SELECT t.* 
FROM Items i 
INNER JOIN ItemTags it ON i.ID = it.ItemID
INNER JOIN Tags t ON it.TagID = t.ID
WHERE i.Created BETWEEN '2018-01-01' and '2018-02-01'
```

The same predicate selects the same 100 items, the database joins through ItemTags to Tags, and returns all the tag data. If you need to know which tag data goes with which item, remember to select it

Answer (score 0):

With Sql Server 2016+ you can return json using FOR JSON AUTO.

```
SELECT i.Name,
(Select t.Name From ItemTags it join Tags t on it.TagId = t.Id Where it.ItemId = i.Id for json auto) as Tags
        from Items i
        where i.Id = 2390
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Question is tagged sql-server-2012 ?

Comment: @CaiusJard, I originally thought that I was using 2012, but I was mistaken.  I have updated the question.